# Spock datatable just accepting integers in Speck inputs

Tags: grails, datatable, spock

I'm working in migrating a large application from Grails 3.3 to Grails 4.

On of the issues we got is related to Spock, the functionality we used in Grails 3.39 seems to be missing: *whe using a datatable to represent the specs, the column for the inputs, seems to be accepting jus integers values*

In the below code just the first line of the specks is passing the text. No the next two, as the spock is transforming to integer befor passing it to `Math.round(value)`

```
import spock.lang.*

@Unroll
 void 'test to demostrate Spock is just accepting integer in datatable column value'() {
   expect:
       Math.round(value) == result   
   where:
   value     | result
   1234      | 1234
   4321.56d  | 4322d
   1111.56f  | 1112d
 }
```

I was noty getting this issue in version 3.3 of Grails.

Thanks in advance for attend this issue

Juan

UPDATE:

UPDATE:

The change of behavior described, actually occurs when the test based on datatable is preceded by a test that includes throwing an excetion

WORK AROUND:

Move the test that includes the exception throwing to be the last test.

Comment: which version of spock are you referring to?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code directly into https://github.com/jeffbrown/juansalvadorspock/blob/a2be4e8ae64df98398535c27ddb406d9aba27a3f/src/test/groovy/demo/SomeSpec.groovy#L8-L18 and that test seems to work fine.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: "whe using a datatable to represent the specs, the column for the inputs, seems to be accepting jus integers values" - It is hard to say what is going wrong in your project but it definitely not the case that only integer values are supported.  Any arbitrary object or primitive may be used.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I have updated the log, the problem is when a test based in datatable is preceded by a test that includes throwing an exception

Comment: Can you please provide an example how to reproduce that with the exception throwing test as you write?

Answer (score 0):

Grails 4 uses *org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.5* and in this version it works as expected (as in other versions of Spock).

Update your specification in this way:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class RoundSpec extends Specification {
    @Unroll
    void 'Math.round(#value) == #result'() {
        setup:
        println "$value as ${value.class}"

        expect:
        Math.round(value) == result

        where:
        value    || result
        1234     || 1234
        4321.56d || 4322
        1111.56f || 1112
    }
}
```

Then you can see that all test cases pass the test and you can also see in the output what data of which class is passed into the test:

[image]

So `Integer`, `Double` and `Float` are passed and not `Integer` in all cases as you write.

What I can see in your test is, that you have `result` value as a `Double` two times, but `Math.round()` returns long each time.

Comment: Hi @cgrim, thanks for your response. The jar file I'm using is `spock-core-1.2-groovy-sources.jar`

Comment: Did you try the code from the answer in your Spock instance? Is the output the same?

Comment: No, you don't use `spock-core-1.2-groovy-sources.jar` because that one only contains, as the name implies, source code and no binaries (class files). You must be using another JAR which in its name specifies both Spock version + Groovy version.